# Different values ​addressing to the same page - PHP

Tags: php

As the title suggests, I have a table called: `table`

contents of the table:

```
id
first name
e-mail
password
role
```

and two users one have a value of `role`:
N

and another value of `role`:
S

after login, address all users to a page called:

```
reindirizza.php
```

login page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';
//REAL_ESCAPE_STRING ANTI STRINGA BUCA DB
$email = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->query("SELECT id, password FROM tabella WHERE email='$email'");
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
$data = $query->fetch_array();
if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
$_SESSION['NOME_SESSIONE'] = true;
//IMPLEMENTAZIONE SICUREZZA PER ACCESSO AI DATI SOLO SE LA SESSIONE DELLA LOGIN PAGE E' UGUALE ALLA PAGINA DOPO DEL LOGIN
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "reindirizza.php";
</script>   
<?php
}else
$messaggio = "Gentilmente inserisci correttamente la tua username e la tua password.";
}}
?>
<?php if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio . "<br><br>"; ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email..."><br>
<input class="form-control" minlength="5" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><br>
</form>
```

the page reindirizza.php, has the task of sorting the users if they have `role` N value, go to the page `n.php`.
If they have value S, go to the page `s.php`

reindirizza.php:

```
<?php
include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabella";
$utente = mysqli_query($VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE, $query);

if (!$query) {
    die(mysqli_error($VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE));
} 
$controlla_utente = mysqli_num_rows($utente);
if($controlla_utente>0){

$dati_utente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($utente);
if ($dati_utente["role"] == 'N') {
header("Location: n.php");    
    }
elseif($dati_utente["role"] == 'S') {
header("Location: s.php"); 
}
} 
?>
```

the problem is that regardless of the role everyone goes to the s.php page

and another thing I would like after the login based on the page where they have to go I could see their id, how do I do it?

Comment: You need to `exit;` after your `header` redirects.

Comment: @cteski implemented, but always go to s.php

Comment: @cteski not sure that's it. The header is in an elseif.

Comment: Double check the SQL then place a `var_dump($dati_utente);` strategically... Selecting wrong thing or not getting result you expect. You are probably seeing a warning/notice as well that would be a hint.

Comment: the problem is : you have no **WHERE** clause in your query at all. You are requesting all records from your table regardless to anything

Comment: ^ and not iterating on them, simply operating on the first "row".

Comment: line `if (!$query) {` makes no sense. it is always false, since you setup query string to this variable few lines before

Comment: @Alex and how would it be written to operate on the single id, which logs in?

Answer (score 0):

Just save user id in session:

```
...
if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
   $_SESSION['NOME_SESSIONE'] = true;
   $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = (int)$data['id'];
...
```

and in your `reindirizza.php` change the query to:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabella WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
...
```

Comment: ok, I did the echo and the correct id of every login user goes out, but to redirect if role is n or s?

Comment: I have no idea what `echo` you are talking about.If you apply this changes I believe your code should start to work as expected.